# Wrong syntax with Multer Library

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, fs, multer

I'm creating an Admin panel where the admin can upload max **5 images**(through multer) and the paths are stored in the cluster(mongoose). There are two folders: Products & OptimizedImages. Initially, I upload them on Products folder and then through Tinify(library for compress images) i put them on OptimizedImages and delete them(with rimraf, because fs.unlink doesn't work).

```
 const results = req.files.map(async file => {

            return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

                await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(product._id, {
                    $push: {
                        paths: {
                            path: file.filename
                        }
                    }
                });

                const src = tinify.fromFile(`./public/Products/${file.filename}`);

                src.toFile(`./public/OptimizedImages/${file.filename}`)
                    .then(() => {
                        rimraf(`./public/Products/${file.filename}`, err => {
                            if (err) {
                                return reject(err)
                            }
                            return resolve(file)
                        })
                    }).catch(err => {
                        throw new Error(err);
                    })

            })

        })

        Promise.all(results)
            .then(resp => {
                console.log(resp);
                return res.redirect('/admin/dashboard');
            }).catch(err => {
                throw new Error(err);
            })
```

But when I upload 5 Images, in the OptimizedImages folder **appear 4 images**, sometimes 5 Images. Sometimes 2 or 3 Images rest in Products folder and 1 Image get compressed... Maybe because the synchronously of the syntax is wrong? I tried also to rimraf.sync() and etc.

**Multer setup: **

```
// Multer Setup
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'public/Products/')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
})

// I tried both but nothing =>

// const upload = multer({ storage, limits: { fieldSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024 } });
const upload = multer({ storage });
```

I'am sure that the problem is caused by the *wrong syntax*. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Please update your question with the repo and tell us which part do you need help instead of just sharing your repo only.

Answer (score 0):

There are some bugs in your codes.

First, as you are calling your DB, I think it is better to send requests to your DB in serial. It means it will finish the `findByIdAndUpdate` one by one instead of sending all requests at once.

Second, you didn't wrap your `rimraf` function properly in promises.

**Example below**

```js
(async function run(req, res) {
  try {
    const results = [];
    for (const file of req.files) {
      const data = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(product._id, {
        $push: {
          paths: {
            path: file.filename,
          },
        },
      });

      results.push(data);

      const src = tinify.fromFile(`./public/Products/${file.filename}`);

      await src.toFile(`./public/OptimizedImages/${file.filename}`);

      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        rimraf(`./public/Products/${file.filename}`, err => {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          }
          resolve();
        });
      });
    }
    console.log(results);
    res.redirect("/admin/dashboard");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: And the part of Promise.all ??? In theory when you use 'new Promise((resolve, reject)) you should then use .then .catch?

Comment: @antoniosalzano, It seems you may not understand clearly about Promises and async functions. You may have a look at [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). They actually are the same thing and async/await is just a syntactic sugar on top of promises. You don't really need `Promise.all` but you can use it as well and it will send all requests to DB at once and it may be not a good practice.

Comment: unfortunately the problem still persists. Can i give you my GitHub repo? I can also give you my tinify key API, there is no problem. Because this is for a client...

Comment: @antoniosalzano, you can share the repo in your question. I think it is not necessary to give me the key.